# How to run production react app in local with local back-end

Tags: reactjs

I have seen using production react app with server in local.

But mostly I found the way is running production react app using express.js with Heroku.

How to running production react app with server in local without any change of code?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

When you run `npm run build` your console should actually say something like the following

```
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

The build script is building your entire app into the build folder, ready to be statically served. However actually serving it require some kind of static file server, like the one they propose.

After running the command serve -s build you can access your production build at localhost (on the specified port).

You can of course run whatever static file server you like, I usually use express for this, however serve seems like the easiest option to just serve your statics files with a single command.

Answer (score 7):

As of date by default for CRA

> serve -s build

will deploy your app on localhost port 5000

**If you want to open on custom port use flag -l**

> serve -s build -l customportnumber

[CRA Deployment Official Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)

Answer (score 3):

make a production build of the react app locally, (run `npm run build` if you are using `create react app`) and then you can use [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) to run it locally by running `serve -s build`. `build` is the folder name of your production build.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of achieving this.

You can use `http-server` or `serve` packages for running local servers.
If on MacOS, you can also use python SimpleHttpServer to host the production build folder.

Reference: https://medium.com/@samratshaw/test-react-production-build-locally-434907be9e49

Comment: For readers that don't know, python 2 is installed by default on MacOs and Linux systems.  If you have python installed on Windows, it works there too. At least for Python 3. I just tested `python -m http.server --directory build` and it works great.  So, it's another option.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these commands

If you are using **NPM**:

1. `npm run build`
2. `npm install -g serve`
3. `npx serve -s build`

---

And if you are using **Yarn**:

1. `yarn build`
2. `yarn global add serve`
3. `npx serve -s build`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run you React application on default `:8000` port it's more convenient to create an nginx proxy server which will run on port `:8000` and proxy your request into your express application which is serving your bundled application running on port for example `:8081` or whatever port you are using.